# Partition Scheme Ubuntu 18.04.2 Server with 2TBHDD

Tags: server, partitioning, samba

I am building a server that will run Samba for 2-5 people, a mail server for myself, a SQL server and maybe a Windows VB. I'm booting from an 8G thumb drive. How should I partition my HDD? This is what I was thinking so far:

- / --> 20G
- /boot --> 1G
- /home --> 550G
- /var --> 200G
- /var/mail --> 75G
- /tmp --> 50G
- /usr --> 20G
- /swapp --> 2G

Comment: Why would you boot from a 8G thumb drive? Why would you make all of these partitions? Management nightmare. How would you back this up?

Comment: If you ask 100 people you will get 100 answers. There is no correct answer for this. I am voting to close this question as the answers are primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

```
/home --> 550G
```

Far too big. On a server you should put personal files on a separate data partition,

```
/var --> 200G
/var/mail --> 75G
/usr --> 20G
```

Why are you limiting youself by creating these partitions?

Just create symlinks or change the settings to set your personal files to your data partition. A mysql database file, apache webserver, your mail etc all have a config file where you can change the location of the files that hold your data.

Partioning your system directories is a thing of the past. Keep /, a swap if you want BUT we nowadays use a swapfile, make a smallish home (even 50Gb is overkill) and make 1 big personal data partition. Easy to backup your own files and you can keep a script there that can reset changes you made to the default Ubuntu. Easy if you want to upgrade your systen: format / and /home. reattach your partition, run the script to change the changes you made and you are good to go.

Comment: Not sure why /home 550GB would far to big, J explains he want to use this as samba server. Sorry but you can use Samba for whatever you wish: sharing,backup and 550GB nowdays are peanuts.. I am not sharing your opinion and also your not offering a solution.

Comment: @Alpy anything user related should be on a separate partition. For a server /home should be treated as an area for an admin to manage the system: adding and deleting users, configuring settings. If the users puts personal data in /home and the admin by mistake deletes that account the users data will also be gone. Seen it before and have seen it go bad. A backup of /home can go bad too if you want to upgrade the system. Samba should also NEVER EVER be related to /home/. Virusses from windows become a attack vector. You do not want a Windows virus get outside of the samba environment.

Answer (score 0):

do not separate the /tmp, /usr /boot from /  just do it like this:

```
/ --> 90G
/home --> 550G
/var --> 275G
```

and swap should be 2x your physical memory

Comment: Swap at 2Xmemory is probably overthinking this. You didn't even ask how much memory they have, and whether they're going to ever hibernate this machine.

Comment: besides that: swap partition? why not stick to the default we use: a swap file. It is dynamic so no need to think about its size

Comment: That is why I did mention swap in the partition, sure this is your call. You can even not set a swap but for high usage you set it normally to 1.5-2x times.

Comment: @Alpy it sounds like you really don't understand swap.

Comment: @Rinzwind re: dynamic swap? /swapfile is a fixed size. When did it become dynamic? Or, do you mean that its size can be changed relatively easily?

Comment: @Rinzwind extra credit... the /swapfile is only used on new fresh installs. Upgrades use an original swap partition, if found.

Comment: @heynnema wrong use of dynamic yes :D

Comment: @heynnema since is a server for a Samba server is quite obvious that he doesnt have more than 16GB as physical memory. So far it was always a finger calculation 1.5-2x times physical memory but this is always free to choose. Also in which way you think I do not understand swap. Be explicit

Comment: @Alpy As my first comments says... you didn't even ask the user how much memory they have (you **assume** they only have 16G), didn't ask about hibernation, didn't ask if they were going to use a /swapfile or a swap partition, and have no idea about their memory utilization. By your estimate, if the user had 64G RAM, then you'd have a 128G swap? No way. Then you also tell Rinzwind, a guy with a rep of 207k, that you don't like his answer. Really?

Comment: Really, who is putting a Samba server with 64GB RAM? Practically nosense. Have you heard about such one??

Comment: @Alpy that's one of my points... until you ask the user, you have no idea what they have, or what to recommend.

Comment: @Alpy I have 8GB of RAM and may upgrade to 16GB or even 32GB depending on the size of my Apache server. I agree with you and henynnema with regards to 64GB -- 8GB should handle my Samba.

Comment: @j_J a 8GB swapfile/swappartition should be enough in this case.